# Spark structured streaming with secured Kafka gets freeze on a log message [INFO StreamExecution: Starting new streaming query.]

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kerberos

In order to use structured streaming in my project, I am testing spark 2.2.0 and Kafka 0.10.1 integration with Kerberos on my hortonworks 2.6.3 environment, I am running below sample code to check the integration. I am able to run the below program on IntelliJ on spark local mode with no issues, but the same program when moved to yarn cluster/client mode on Hadoop cluster it get stuck on below log message `18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO StreamExecution: Starting new streaming query`.

To do a sanity check on the secured Hadoop cluster, I ran spark 2.2.0 PI example, it is working fine and I am also able to produce and consume messages from Kafka on Hadoop cluster using `kafka-console-producer.sh` and `kafka-console-consumer.sh`.

Sorry for this long post as this is a very broad question, I need your inputs in order to make this work.

**Sample Program:**

```
object DemoSparkStreamingWithKafkaJob {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
    val spark = getSparkSession
    import spark.implicits._
    val Array(kafkaBrokerList, srcTopic,destTopic, security) = args

     import spark.implicits._

     val df: DataFrame = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokerList)
      .option("kafka.security.protocol", security)
      .option("subscribe", srcTopic)
      .load


    val keyValueDf = df
      .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
      .as[(String, String)]

    val query = keyValueDf
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .start()
    query.awaitTermination()

   }

  def getSparkSession()=
  {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .appName("KAFKA_SPARK_TEST_APP")
       .getOrCreate()
    spark
  }
}
```

**kafka_jaas.conf:**

```
KafkaClient {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useTicketCache=true
renewTicket=true
serviceName="{{kafka_bare_jaas_principal}}";
};
Client {
com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
useKeyTab=true
keyTab="{{kafka_keytab_path}}"
storeKey=true
useTicketCache=false
serviceName="zookeeper"
principal="{{kafka_jaas_principal}}";
};
```

**Spark-submit Command:**

```
./spark-submit \
--name TEST_JOB_SPARK_STREAM_WITH_KAFKA \
--verbose \
--master yarn \
--deploy-mode client \
--num-executors 1  \
--executor-memory 1g \
--executor-cores 1 \
--repositories http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/ \
--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235 \
--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=1 \
--files /home/user/sparktest/kafka_jaas.conf#kafka_jaas.conf,/home/user/sparktest/user.headless.keytab#user.headless.keytab \
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/user/sparktest/kafka_jaas.conf" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UseG1GC -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/user/sparktest/kafka_jaas.conf" \
--class com.brokerfmc.demo.DemoSparkStreamingWithKafkaJob /home/user/sparktest/demo.jar kafka01.broker.com:6667,kafka02.broker.com:6667 src_topic dest_topic SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

**Spark Console Output:**

```
18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO AbstractLogin: Successfully logged in.
18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO KerberosLogin: TGT refresh thread started.
18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO KerberosLogin: TGT valid starting at: Thu Jan 25 13:07:52 UTC 2018
18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO KerberosLogin: TGT expires: Thu Jan 25 23:08:08 UTC 2018
18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO KerberosLogin: TGT refresh sleeping until: Thu Jan 25 21:26:00 UTC 2018
18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values:
        metric.reporters = []
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka01.broker.com:6667, kafka02.broker.com:6667]
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        enable.auto.commit = false
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        interceptor.classes = null
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        client.id = consumer-1
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        max.poll.records = 1
        check.crcs = true
        request.timeout.ms = 40000
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
        group.id = spark-kafka-source-c3ecdc95-df8e-4381-be28-c504abd91dba--805260723-driver-0
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.key.password = null
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        session.timeout.ms = 30000
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        security.protocol = SASL_PLAINTEXT
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        auto.offset.reset = earliest

18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka version : 0.10.0.1
18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO AppInfoParser: Kafka commitId : a7a17cdec9eaa6c5
18/01/25 14:19:59 INFO StreamExecution: Starting new streaming query.
```

**Pom file:**

```
<properties>
        <provided.scope>provided</provided.scope>
        <hdp.version>2.6.3.0-235</hdp.version>
        <spark-excel.version>0.9.8</spark-excel.version>
        <spark.version>2.2.0.2.6.3.0-235</spark.version>
        <kafka.version>0.10.1.2.6.3.0-235</kafka.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <id>HDPReleases</id>
            <name>HDP Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.hortonworks.com/content/repositories/releases/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

     <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.crealytics</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-excel_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark-excel.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Comment: I would suspect "--executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1" in ./spark-submit, as the Spark app can read and not process data. Have you tried to increase these values ?

Comment: @PaulLeclercq , I incremented cores and executor, It doesn't work.

Comment: Hello , I am now getting  ERROR StreamExecution: Query [id = 01bd97ea-6d2c-446c-a366-491d252925aa, runId = cc8dc932-9297-47c5-b30b-007624c03163] terminated with error org.apache.kafka.common.errors.GroupAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access group: spark-kafka-source-d690d270-7092-4aed-82c2-97fdfd80d0ed--604732661-driver-2

Comment: Check with your Kafka admin about ACL  : https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#security_authz

Comment: @PaulLeclercq I cant configure acl for groupid in kafka, because in spark structured streaming group.id is generated by spark.

Comment: You can set it via the property `.option("group.id", "MyGroyp")` like here : https://github.com/polomarcus/Spark-Structured-Streaming-Examples/blob/f6da67034ee5e231cdebb909ce712ed78b3c87fb/src/main/scala/kafka/KafkaSource.scala#L46

Comment: @PaulLeclercq, I tried this option,  spark2 set's it own group-id like this spark-kafka-source-40796d08-889d-430f-bac8-af00aa307ec9--2051427263-driver-2 and ends up with NoAuthorize error.